# Force 404 with PHP and .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

**I am attempting to throw my own 404 in PHP** depending on certain GET vars. But the following is not working. I can confirm that the pge header is coming back with a '404 status code' though. .htaccess just doesn't seem to be redirecting correctly. **Am I missing something?**

**PHP Code:**

```
if(!$_GET['page']){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}
```

**.htaccess Code:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing Apache doesn't throw a 404 error since the page actually does exist. Maybe you should add a redirect to the 404 page in php?

Comment: Don't redirect to a 404 error page, that'll turn it into a 200 request. Just have PHP include the error page's contents.

Comment: @Marc But he's already responding with a 404 status code, he shouldn't have to remove that part.

Comment: @Andre yes, but to do a redirect, it'd have to be a 301 error code. You can't output 404 not found + 301 go elsewhere. Apache doesn't do a redirect to serve up a 404 page. It's just an internal rewrite that dumps out the contents of the specified 404 page, WITHOUT ever doing a redirect.

Comment: If the page exists and is visible to the web, then a 404 is inappropriate. Since you are checking values and throwing an error if the value(s) are inappropriate, a 412 Precondition Failed error might be better.

Comment: unauthorized is for failed authentication. Issuing this code for a 'page not found' error would invalidate a user's loggin (assuming basic http auth), forcing them to log in again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as Apache's concerned, it's done its job as it has properly found the page/script that the user's request called for. The fact that the script is outputting a 404 header is irrelevant to Apache, since its job was completed properly.

You'd need to have your PHP script output the 404 header, and include the page the Apache 404 handler points at it:

```
if (!$_GET['page']) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    include('404.html');
    exit();
}
```

Don't do a redirect to the 404 page, as that'd just turn the hit into a normal GET request, with a 200 OK result.

Comment: @Mark: You had a small typo in your header syntax. Fixed it for you. Also, I'm not sure if it matters, but when I output a header with a status code in PHP, I like to make sure it's overridden, like so: `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);`

Comment: What is the point in serving the header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); if I am just going to include the 404.html page manually?

Comment: `include('404.html');` I would do `readfile('404.html');` instead, as `404.html` does not suggests that it's expected to execute any PHP code.

Comment: @pagewil: Because the status code is information for _the client_ (i.e. a browser, webcrawler etc.) The contents of 404.html is information for _the user_.

Comment: @pagewil it will tell the browser and crawlers that the page does not exists (the 404 page is for the user, and the 404 status is for programs).

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot make the error page start with a number on a XAMPP test server I know...**

***It may be true for windows ... period***.

that one eluded me for *hours*!

Try renaming your error page to:

```
error404.html
```

then change your .htaccess Error section for your 404 to:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

And don't forget to start it with the forward slash. That will fix it.